# Укажите наибольшее возможное значение x

Tags: python, алгоритм, математика, числа, арифметика

Программа вводит натуральное число x, выполняет преобразования, а затем выводит одно число. Укажите **наибольшее** возможное значение x,**не превосходящее 2 000 000 000**, при вводе которого программа выведет число 12.

**python**

```
x = int(input())
a=0
b=10
while x > 0:
 d = x % 6
 if d > a:
    a = d
 if d < b:
    b = d
 x = x // 6
print(a*b)
```

я нашел пары чисел, которые сложив, можно получить 12(ЗАМЕТИМ: что 12 получается в результате a*b=12):

1 и 11

2 и 10

3 и 9

4 и 8

5 и 7

6 и 6

Comment: проставьте отступы в коде

Comment: @n1tr0xs для чего и где поставить??все вроде нормально , все по заданию, копировал оттуда, там также

Comment: ну этот код не запуститься, если его скопировать и вставить.

Comment: @n1tr0xs все нормально только что скопировал и все запускается)

Comment: тогда извините меня

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По-моему, такого нет - если только не имеется в виду переполнение машинное...

```
22
36*22+22
36*(36*22+22)+22
36*(36*(36*22+22)+22)+22
```

и так далее...

Главное - чтоб была мигалка остатков 3 и 4. Так что это не единственный вариант ad infinitum.

Вот пример для более чем 1800-значного числа: https://ideone.com/Fzylq8

**Update** для обновленного вопроса.

Наибольшее число до 2000000000 имеет вид в шестеричной системе счисления
4444...443. Лгко посчитать, что наибольшим числом такого вида, не превосходящим 2000000000, является 1741425867

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103990/discussion-on-answer-by-harry-----x).